# Selective redirect to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this for redirecting all my request through index.php except select few.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|olddir|smestuff|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I want to shift few things (directories) to new domain, so I want to know how can I redirect `olddir|smestuff` (*//from above example*) to new domain and keep everything else safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already don't redirect `olddir` and `smestuff`, so add:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(olddir|smestuff)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

which will cause a browser redirect to the new domain.

Comment: @Shishant I actually think you could add it below the above code or immediately after the RewriteEngine directive.

Comment: just to notice that you could do it without mod_rewrite with Redirect or RedirectMatch directives in your apache configuration as well.